# Reactjs passing uppercase dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem passing dynamic variable to other component.
I have array of objects, which have other objects inside:

```
var myArr = {"1": {
"name": "rose", 
"symbol":"ros", 
"quotes": { 
    "USD": {
        "price": "10"
    }
}}}
```

This is how I am trying to pass variables to my component:

```
<MyComponent
 key={index}
 name={item.name}
 symbol={item.symbol}
 price={item.quotes.USD.price}
/>
```

Doing like this, I get error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'USD' of undefined
```

Also I tried to pass price variable like this:

```
<MyComponent
 key={index}
 name={item.name}
 symbol={item.symbol}
 price={item.quotes.${USD}.price}
/>
```

But got Failed to compile error:

```
Failed to compile
price={item.quotes.${USD}.price}
                   ^
```

How can I pass dynamic variable which contains uppercase?

Comment: did you check the value for `item.qoutes` in console log?

Comment: You have mispelled quotes, and put both spellings in this post, could that be related in your code too?

Comment: the value of item.qoutes is defined before passing to MyComponent

Comment: @Dan At his first try the property is `qoutes` and which is as per variable definition, at the second try the `quotes` is used and throwing undefined error.

Comment: @Paulius Notice to the spelling.

Comment: Its not the spelling. its USD vs usd. I would get value if there would be 'usd', but not 'USD' (uppercase)

Comment: @Paulius `qoutes` vs `quotes`

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar once again, it's not the qoutes vs quotes issue. Look at the errors I am getting.

Comment: `price={item[index].quotes.USD.price}` ??

Comment: did worked this! Thank you @BhojendraRauniyar !!!

Comment: updated my answer.

Comment: @Paulius you may accept the answer if you think that has helped to you.

Answer (score 1):

After carefully reviewing your code I found that you're missing the index:

```
price={item[index].quotes.USD.price}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do something like this:

```
var myArr = {"1": {
"name": "rose", 
"symbol":"ros", 
"quotes": { 
"USD": {
    "price": "10"
}
}}}

myArr['1'].quotes.USD.price
```

(or)

```
myArr['1'].quotes['USD'].price
```